# Determine High and Low Bytes of x and y from a byte array

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I want to send an Android Bitmap to a printer (Mobile Bluetooth Printer Bixolon SPP R-200) using their SDK I can convert the Bitmap to a byte Array. For reference purposes (and to understand what I am taking about) check out the Bixolon Command manual [here](http://www.bixolon.com/com_updata/bixolon_download/SPP-R200%20Command%20Manual_English_Rev_1_00%282%29.pdf). And this is how I proceed:

Send a command to the printer, to tell it, how I want my printout to be aligned (left = 0, right = 2, center = 1) using the following command:

```
    byte[] command = { 27, 97, 0 };
```

The 27 and 97 are a command from the Bixolon Command manual - the zero means "left aligned". I then send this command to the printer using the SDKs write(byte[]) command (which succeeds).

The next step is where I am having trouble: I want to send the "Print raster bit image" command to the printer and the first part is easy:

```
    byte[] command2 = { 29, 118, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

The 29, 118 and 48 together make up the command called "GS v 0" (literal translation when using a ascii conversion chart on the above numbers) which is described on page 126 in the referenced Bixolon manual. The first zero sets the horizontal and vertical DPI to 203.

Now the part I am stuck with: According to the manual, the remaining 4 zeros have to be replaced by:

```
xL  xH  yL  yH  d1...d
```

which I assume to be x Position Low Byte, x Position High Byte, y position Low byte etc... (not sure what d1...d stands for though?).

In the SDK they're filling those last 4 Bytes with the following code:

```
    int width = myBitmap.getWidth();
    int height = myBitmap.getHeight();
    int bytesOfWidth = width / 8 + (width % 8 != 0 ? 1 : 0);

    dimensionCommand[4] = (byte) (bytesOfWidth % 256);
    dimensionCommand[5] = (byte) (bytesOfWidth / 256);
    dimensionCommand[6] = (byte) (height % 256);
    dimensionCommand[7] = (byte) (height / 256);
```

But I don't understand why. Is this how you calculate the high and low bytes of the x/y positions?

However - sending this command to the printer works too, and in the last step my Bitmap that has been converted to a byte array get's successfully transferred as well (at least no IO Error occurs), but nothing is being printed (although the paper moves and there seem to be two pixels being printed on the left side of the paper). So I suspected maybe the above calculation of the high and low bytes for the x and y coordinates of the Bitmap are wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines

```
int bytesOfWidth = width / 8 + (width % 8 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
dimensionCommand[4] = (byte) (bytesOfWidth % 256);
dimensionCommand[5] = (byte) (bytesOfWidth / 256);
```

look suspicious.  I would use the same computation for width as there's for height.  I would also use bitwise AND and bit-shift instead of `%` and `/` operators, which are rather slow in comparison:

```
int width = myBitmap.getWidth();
int height = myBitmap.getHeight();

dimensionCommand[4] = (byte) (width & 0xFF);
dimensionCommand[5] = (byte) ((width >> 8) & 0xFF);
dimensionCommand[6] = (byte) (height & 0xFF);
dimensionCommand[7] = (byte) ((height >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried it, but still no change - however this could be because of another problem with the printer communication, so your answer could be right, I'll keep trying some more.

Answer (score 0):

Lose that bytesOfWidth calculation, it doesn't make sense. Just pass the width through.

The bytes d1,d2,...d3, that follow this header are the raster **d**ata. According to [the online manual](http://www.bixolon.co.uk/html/SRP-R200/SPP-R200%20Command%20Manual_english.pdf) this raster data is 1 *byte* per pixel, not 1 bit as I think your previous question assumed.

Comment: You mean pass it through like Aleks suggested or simply use: dimensionCommand[4] = (byte) (width);
dimensionCommand[5] = (byte) (width);
dimensionCommand[6] = (byte) (height);
...
without any calculation at all?

Comment: On an addition note: I am converting my Bitmap (created using Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) using the Bixolon's SDK  Method BxlBitmap.bitmap2printerData(Bitmap, width, level) however that method does a lot of stuff, so I don't really have a guarantee, that my Bitmap isnt messed up. But then the SDK uses that method for printing their Bitmaps, which works, as opposed to my printing attempts.

Comment: I didn't see Aleks' suggestion, but yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Thank you both, I accepted ALex's answer, because I think he was a bit fast (I cant see the exact timestamps however), unfortunately it doesn't help with the printing, but if it's correct I guess I should get it to work sooner or later.

Comment: One thing I don't understand: Bixolons SDK printing works (mine doesnt) and they do that weird  bytesOfWidth calculation ... I really wonder what's the supposed purpose of it... maybe some weird printer quirk they're catering to .. ?

Comment: The bytesOfWidth calculation is for 1bpp... a clearer expression would be 'bytesOfWidth = (width+7)/8;'. The manual implies 8bpp and this code says 1bpp... one of them has to be wrong. If the code works then the manual's wrong. How are you assembling the 1bpp bytes? I imagine that could be a ripe area for errors.

Comment: If you mean how I convert the Bitmap to a byte array: I am using an SDK Method for that purpose (the same the SDK itself uses when converting images to byte array). The SDK Code first scales the bitmap down to the printer width, if it's larger, then it creates a ByteBuffer, to which it copies the Bitmap's pixels using myBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(targetBuffer). Then it dumps the buffer into a byte array. At the end it calls some internal methods called makeDiffusionImageData and makeMonoGsvData which further modify the image byte array - then the result is returned...

Comment: Mystery solved at last :) I can print now, the issue was the SDKs bitmap conversion, I am doing it myself now, plus one SDK call and it seriously prints :O . Thanks everyone for ur help !